# Android: Shifting array one position to make a dynamic graph

Tags: android

**UPDATE:**

Runs like a charm now. With the help of Alex Klimashevsky who pointed me in the right direction. Basically I meshed up the for loop. This is what it should be:

```
for(int a = 1; a < x.length; a++) {
    y[(a)]=yprev[a-1];
}
y[0]=value_i/10;

for(int a = 0; a < x.length; a++) {
    yprev[a]=y[a];
}
```

Thanks!

Maybe someone can tell me what is going wrong:
It is a really basic plotting program, but it is good enough for now.

**I declared this on the top of my view class:**

```
private int[] x = {50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110,120,130};
private int[] y= {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};
private int[] yprev={500,500,500,500,100,500,500,500,500};
```

**And I put this within onDraw:**

```
for(int a =  (x.length-1); a ==0; a--) {
    y[(a+1)]=yprev[i]; //Shift everything one place to the right
}
y[0]=value/10; //Fill in the newest value for temperature on the first index

for(int a =  (x.length); a ==0; a--) {
    yprev[a]=y[a]; //Store the latest array, such it can be re-used in the next cycle**
}

paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setColor(Color.RED);

Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(x[0], y[0]);
for(int b = 1; b < x.length; b++) {
    path.lineTo(x[b], y[b]);
}
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Plotting works, but somehow it doesn't shift my plot. The new value is every time plotted on the first index and all other values remain 500.
Any ideas?

Best regards,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First looking gets this:

```
for(int a =  (x.length-1); a >=0; a--) {
    y[(a+1)]=yprev[i]; //Shift everything one place to the right
}
y[0]=value/10; //Fill in the newest value for temperature on the first index

for(int a =  (x.length); a >=0; a--) {
    yprev[a]=y[a]; //Store the latest array, such it can be re-used in the next cycle**
}
```

In your code this loops are not working

Comment: Thanks, that is true ofcourse. I also noticed that yprev[i] should be ypreg[a]. I changed everything but now my app crashes at start up even before anything was drawn. Changing the For statement back to == makes the app running again but makes the loops faulty.